# Create your Own Design Theme

Tags: design, default, skin, app

I like to design my own skin of the website. I created 2 new folders with the
name examplefolder in the directory, the path is:

1) app/design/frontend/default/examplefolder
2) skin/frontend/default/exmaplefolder

In the configs->design->Themes->standart I put my folder (examplefolder).

In the frontend my website should appear only in text. No formattings.

But this not works, there is no ajustment to my modification. I cleard the caches in magento and in the browser.

Has anyone an idea whats wrong ?

Many thanks for reply

Thanks but it still does not work. I can adjust the config as you mentioned. But all of my changes I try to do in the folder comicworld (see picture) has no affect to the fronted. I try to change again the current Package Name to comicworld but the following mistake message appeared: magento theme package with this name does not exist and cannot be set.

Thanks for further assistance [image]

Answer (score 2):

```
Go to System > Configuration > Design > Pacage and System > Configuration > Design > Pacage
```

[image]

Comment: up vote
0
down vote
accept
Thanks but it still does not work. I can adjust the config as you mentioned. But all of my changes I try to do in the folder comicworld (see picture) has no affect to the fronted. I try to change again the current Package Name to comicworld but the following mistake message appeared: magento theme package with this name does not exist and cannot be set.

Thanks for further assistance